# Poincaré 3-homology sphere

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Can the Poincaré $3$-homology sphere be smoothly embeded in $\mathbb R^4$?
If it is not the case, how can we fix it?

Comment: The answer is no, as a google search found for me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rokhlin%27s_theorem#The_Rokhlin_invariant .  What do you mean by "how can we fix it"?

Comment: Any homology $3$-sphere admits a locally flat topological embedding in $4$-space, by a result of Freedman. Is this the kind of fix you were after?

Comment: I wonder if someone would add here the reference for the Freedman result.  Thanks!

Comment: why is this question closed? It seems to be related to several interesting things.

Comment: I didn't vote to close but the question needs a fair bit of work following the guidelines of http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, given M any homology 3-sphere then M x [0,1] can be embeded in R^4.
Is this right?

Comment: In the book "4-Manifolds and Kirby Calculus" by Robert E. Gompf,András I. Stipsicz, pag.345.

Comment: They admit topological embeddings but not necessarily smooth embeddings; the page you cite is specific about that point.

Comment: ...but I cannot understand why in this case the Whitney embedding result doesn't work...it hold for a general smooth manifold...
is a homology 3-sphere not smooth?

Comment: Wouldn't Whitney embedding theorem need 6 dimensions?  Am I missing something?  Wikipedia says you start with an immersion with transverse self-intersections, then you fix this.  (I paraphrase.)